# Deploy .Net Core 3 en Windows Server 2012 R2 - Error 500.19

Tags: iis, .net-core, windows-server

Al hacer el deploy de una REST API basada en ASP.NET Core 3.1 en Windows Server 2012 R2 arroja el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He instalado

- .net core SDK
- .net core runtime
- .net core windows server hosting
- c++ redistributable
- KB2999226

El appPool esta configurado de la siguiente manera:

- Versión .Net: sin código administrado
- Modo canalización: integrada
- Habilitar app 32 bits: true (si estaba en false al ejecutar la App se detenía el appPool)

La carpeta a donde apunta el sitio tiene todo los permisos.

Realice innumerables búsquedas y no encuentro una solución.

Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente logre encontrar el problema.
Básicamente estaba usando EF Core pero faltaban librerías. Se soluciono incorporando al proyecto Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational